# Dynamic library using Select method

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dynamic, entity

I am using the Dynamic library.

I would like to have the same return as the following linq returns me:

```
var sql = from p in context.TB_PEOPLE
          select new
          {
             NAME = p.NAME,
             PHONES = p.TB_PHONE.Select(ph => ph.PHONE)
          };
```

I'm having trouble returning to the field from a related table that has a relationship 1..N, with eg

```
TB_PEOPLE> TB_PHONE
```

I tried to do something like:

```
 var sql = context.TB_PEOPLE.Select("TB_PEOPLE. TB_PHONE.PHONE");
```

But TB_PHONE is an ICollection in TB_PEOPLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is kind of old, but Microsoft's Dynamic Linq Library does not support this out of the box.

However, I've recently added support for doing this in my version of the Dynamic Linq Library (https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic.Library).

Here is what is would look like based on your example:

```
var sql = context.TB_PEOPLE.Select("new (NAME, TB_PHONE.Select(PHONE) AS PHONES)")
```

If you are using .NET 4.0+, you can easily access the results like this:

```
var phones = sql.First().PHONES;
```

Otherwise, you'll have to use reflection to get the results.